# Can a resource slow down a webpage load?

Tags: performance, http, browser, timeout, loading

If I call a resource in a webpage (e.g. a pixel from tracker.com at the beginning of body), and tracker.com is very slow to answer (e.g. >10s or even timeout), what are the consequences to my webpage load?

Will the other resources (script, images, css, etc) be displayed as usual?
If not, is asynchronous tag an option?

Comment: what do you mean with 'call a resource in a webpage'?

Comment: a pixel, image or an iframe from another domain

Comment: what is 'pixel' in html? image and iframe from another domain is already loaded asynchronously by most browsers.

Comment: sorry, pixel = image with height=1 and width=1 (it is mainly used for trackers). when i try this code ; '<iframe src="http://www.google.com:81" > hello world' then
  hello world is not displayed (chrome, firefox)

Comment: OK, so pixel is nothing that normal image ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading resources, as you call it, will not delay the `domready` or `document ready` page event, however it will delay the `load` page event. The actual behaviour of page loading depends on browser - the browser should download the resources from different hosts in paralel. It will not affect the whole page rendering, unless you use images with unspecified width and height - in that case browser must re-render the page after receiving the image.
So when well designed, the only problem would be the delayed load event.

In case of very slow-loading resources you can avoid that by the use the "asynchrounous tag" - just handle the domready event and place new tags. E.g. in jquery use:

```
$(function () {
    // this code will be run after dom ready event
});
```